# Gitlab: Concat file based variables

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

I need to replace a variable value inside a file based gitlab variable like below.

**File based variable:**

- Name: app_service_dev_env
- Value:

  iam_role_name="xxxx" 
  lambda_s3_bucket_name = "xxxxx"
  lambda_s3_key="xxxxx"

**Variable:**

- Name: ENV
- Value: dev

Below is what I am looking to implement

before_script:
-cat ${app_service_${ENV}_env} > dev.txt

Getting error: ERROR: Job failed: exit code 2

Could anyone please let me know how to resolve this?

How could I resolve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The **file** [variable type](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/variables/#cicd-variable-types) creates a *file*. They are not *environment* variables. The key is the path to the file.

```yaml
before_script:
  - cat app_service_dev_env > dev.txt
```

Though, you could simply make the name of your file variable `dev.txt`

As for your `ENV` variable, with your current setup you can do something like this:

```yaml
before_script:
  - cat "app_service_${ENV}_env"
```

Comment: Thank you! I will verify and check if it solves the issue

Comment: Is it possible to have something like cat ${$service_name}_${ENV}_env} > dev.txt or any way if we can acheive this?

Comment: @GiridharMarri sure. Since GitLab 14.3, you can leverage [nested variable expansion](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/variables/where_variables_can_be_used.html#nested-variable-expansion) -- `variables: FOO: "${SERVICE_NAME}_${ENV}_env"` this is also generally supported in Bash, or your preferred shell.

Comment: Sorry for not being clear earlier. I am trying to parameterize gitlab file variable something like ${Service_Name}_${ENV}_env and use it like:  cat ${$Service_Name}_${ENV}_env} > dev_env.txt. Is this possible?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure I'm understanding fully either... but if I'm understanding your meaning correctly -- you want to dynamically name the file type variable. I don't believe this is possible. The file type variables can only be set as Project/group/instance CI/CD variables and these variables cannot be parameterized and their keys do not support variable expansion. You may find what you need by looking at artifacts and dotenv reports instead... but it's not entirely clear to me the reason why you need this particular solution. Sounds like an XY problem. @GiridharMarri